# Adding rows to a Google Sheet using the R Package googlesheets

Tags: r, google-sheets, r-googlesheets

I'm using the `googlesheets` package (CRAN version, but available here: https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets) to read data from a Google Sheet in R, but would now like to add rows. Unfortunately, every time use `gs_add_row` for an existing sheet I get the following error:

```
Error in gsheets_POST(lf_post_link, XML::toString.XMLNode(new_row)) : 
  client error: (405) Method Not Allowed
```

I followed the tutorial on Github to create a sheet and add rows as follows:

```
library(googlesheets)
library(dplyr)
df.colnames <- c("Project Short Name","Project Start Date","Proj Stuff")
my.df <- data.frame(a = "cannot be empty", b = "cannot be empty", c = "cannot be empty")
colnames(my.df) <- df.colnames
## Create a new workbook populated by this data.frame:
mynewSheet <- gs_new("mynewsheet", input = my.df, trim = TRUE)
## Append Element
mynewSheet <- mynewSheet %>% gs_add_row(input = c("a","b","c"))
mynewKey <- mynewSheet$sheet_key
```

Rows are added successfully, I even get the cheery message `Row successfully appended.`

I now provide `mynewKey` to `gs_key`, as I would if this were a new sheet I were working with and attempt to add a new row using `gs_add_row` (Note: before evaluating these lines, I navigate to the Google Sheet and make it public to the web):

```
myExistingWorkbook <- gs_key(mynewKey, visibility = "public")
## Attempt to gs_add_row
myExistingWorkbook <- myExistingWorkbook %>% gs_add_row(input = c("a","b","c"), ws="Sheet1", verbose = TRUE)

Error in gsheets_POST(lf_post_link, XML::toString.XMLNode(new_row)) : 
  client error: (405) Method Not Allowed
```

Things that I have tried:

1) Published the Google Sheet to the web (as per https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets/issues/126#issuecomment-118751652)

2) Enabled the sheet as editable to the public

## Notes

In my actual example, I have an existing Google Sheet with many worksheets within it that I would like to add rows to. I have tried to use a minimal example here to understand my error, I can also provide a link to the specific worksheet that I would like to update as well.

I have raised an issue on the package's github page here, https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets/issues/168

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`googlesheets::gs_add_row()` and `googlesheets::gs_edit_cells()` make POST requests to the Sheets API. This requires that the visibility be set to "private".

Above, when you register the Sheet by key, please do so like this:

`gs_key(mynewKey, visibility = "private")`

If you want this to work even for Sheets you've never visited in the browser, then add `lookup = FALSE` as well:

`gs_key(mynewKey, lookup = FALSE, visibility = "private")`

Comment: Thanks!! Really appreciate this package and your investigating of this :)

Comment: Your answer saved a ton of my time!